# Android studio 2.2 and 2.3 beta 2 freeze when debugging on OSX

Tags: android, macos, debugging, android-studio-2.2

So when I go to run the debugger in android studio the entire IDE freezes. I can't even scroll in a file.

The debugger starts, and the app begins to start, I see some logs, then nothing.

I've tried my LG Nexus 5x with a wired usb and adb over wifi, and the emulator. I've tried the latest stable (2.2) and the latest downlaodable beta (2.3 Beta 2). Both still freeze. I'm able to run the app, and a coworker on windows is able to run the debugger.

I'm fresh out of ideas, anyone?

Comment: i had the same when debugger type was `Hybrid` after change to `Java` everything started working, of course your case can be different....

Comment: Had to change mine to 'native' 

If you make your comment and answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: oh come in, it was just a wild guess...

Comment: People get stuck up in this kind of thing here. Figured I'd offer to please the lords of this place. Plus you know, it did actually fix things.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  While using the Native option for the debugger stopped the freezing, breakpoints no longer worked.  I went back to the Auto option and removed all breakpoints from the app and the app was debuggable again.